# Soft(standard) ethernet cable doesn't work with internet port in hawawei router (HG255s)

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, cabling

I have HG255s hawawei router which is connected to the ISP as follow:

The HG255s router -> hard(solid) ethernet cable -> an ethernet port in the wall -> hard(solid) ethernet cable in the wall -> media converter -> Fibre cable -> the ISP.

Now the router is in another room and the walls block the wifi signals , so i bought another soft(stranded) 30m ethernet CAT-5 cable. When i tried to connect the stranded cable to the internet port in the hawawei router, it didnt work.

Like this:
 Hawawei router -> soft(stranded) ethernet cable -> ethernet port in the wall -> hard(solid) ethernet cable in the wall -> media converter -> Fibre cable -> the ISP.

But when i connect it like this it worked:
My pc -> tplink router -> stranded ethernet cable -> hawawei router -> hard ethernet -> the wall -> solid conductir ethernet cable in the wall -> media converter -> fiber cable -> ISP.

So my question is, why didnt it work when i connect the stranded etherent directly from the wall to the hawawei router ? . It seems like the stranded ethernet doesn't work with the internet port but works with the lan port. Thanks for reading.

solid ethernet cable = hard ethernet cable | 
stranded ethernet cable = soft ethernet cable

Comment: With proper terminations, the two types are essentially the same and perform the same. Check the connections at the connector points. It is a bit harder to make tight long lasting connections with stranded cable

Comment: We have the two type in some clients and over a reasonable run the two type perform essentially the same for us - that is, the user does not see a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stranded cable (24 and 26 AWG) is limited to patch cords and **10-meter lengths** within a **100-meter channel** (total)

Your stranded cable is 60ft past the recommendation by the TIA and ISO/IEC.

Use **solid conductor cable** for the 90ft section. Stranded cables exhibit 20 to 50% more attenuation than solid copper conductors (20% for 24 AWG and 50% for 26 AWG). This is why it worked when connected to two devices directly. (it was within specification). Remember, each link in the chain of RJ-45 wall outlets and connectors introduces more signal loss/insertion loss. So, when you used the stranded in the longer chain of solid cable, you introduced too much resistance into the total of the Ethernet channel, and pushed it out of spec.

Reference:

https://www.flukenetworks.com/blog/cabling-chronicles/considerations-choosing-stranded-vs-solid-cable

Comment: Hmmmm, it's the interfaces that will dictate the speed. Unless that stranded cable is CAT-5, it should be gigabit. (Provided both nics connected are capable of that speed.)

Comment: i discovered from the router info that the solid cable in the wall and to the router in gigabit cable , but the standard one from the first router to the second one is 100 Mbps , i think thats why it didnt work , connecting gigabit to 100 directly will not work , but making a router between them , somehow adjusts the signals and bandwidth i think . if you think this can be added and its the main cause

Comment: You have mis-understood the problem. Unless it's older cat-5, the cable will not determine the speed. Cat5e, cat-6, cat-6a, will all be exactly the same speed if the network interfaces are 1Gbps. If adding any link in the chain of these cables degrades back to 100Mbps it needs to be re-terminated. Adding a device Inbetween repeats the signal, so from that device onward it's another 100 meters, and the same resistance guidelines apply.